# When I apply filters in my datatable it appears without style

Tags: datatables

When I apply a filter in my datable I call the same function that load the data on the table but this time it appears without style, find-box, prev-next ...
here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dataTable').dataTable();
        } );             
        // ----este array vendria de una consulta sql----           
        miArray = [[11,22,33,44,55,"22/11/2012",99,86,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111],[11,22,33,44,55,"11/06/2011",77,88,99,1010,1111]];

        function cargar(miArray){
            document.getElementById("divTabla").innerHTML = ""
            var tabla= "<table name='tabla1' id='dataTable'><thead><tr><th>Tipo de documento</th><th>Tipo de documento</th><th>Tipo de documento</th><th>Codigo de documento</th><th>Descripcion de documento</th><th>Fecha de documento</th><th>Codigo de proveedor</th><th>Descripcion de proveedor</th><th>Importe</th><th>Importe IVA</th><th>Total a pagar</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
                for (i=0;i<miArray.length;i++){ 
                        tabla = tabla + '<tr>'
                    for (j=0;j<miArray[i].length;j++){              
                        tabla = tabla +'<td></td>'                      
                    }   
                    tabla = tabla + '</tr>'     
                }
                tabla = tabla +'</tbody></table>'                   
                document.getElementById("divTabla").innerHTML = tabla               
                h=1
                for (i=0;i<miArray.length;i++){
                    for (j=0;j<miArray[i].length;j++){          
                        document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[h].cells[j].innerHTML = miArray[i][j]         
                    }   
                h++ 
                }       
        }
        function filtroP(){
            arrayP = []
            var h=0;
            for (i=0;i<miArray.length;i++){
                if (miArray[i][6]== document.form1.prov.value){
                    arrayP[h]=miArray[i]
                    h++
                }
            }
            alert(arrayP)
            cargar(arrayP); 
        }               
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you blow apart the table and readding it in `cargar` when you set `innerHtml`.  If you change the structure of the table directly you may need to reinvoke Datatables to reinitalize it for the new table.

I'm not totally sure what your code is supposed to do but consider using the `fnFilter` function already in datatables to do filtering instead.  See http://datatables.net/api#fnFilter

You also might like `fnDeleteRow` http://datatables.net/api#fnDeleteRow